# C++ MFC - Not receiving CBN_EDITCHANGE message on CBS_DROPDOWN combobox in a toolbar

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc, toolbar

I have an mfc application where my mainframe contains multiple CDockablePanes.

In some of the CDockablePanes I have a CMFCToolbar and a CTreeView.

When I receive the AFX_WM_RESETTOOLBAR message in my mainframe class, I use CMFCToolBar::ReplaceButton to add a CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton to my toolbar.

This works fine and I am able to use the combobox as expected however I want to receive a notification each time the combo box's edit control's text is changed (Each key press etc) but I have not been able to catch a CBN_EDTITCHANGE message at all.

I have been using this line in my message map:
    ON_CBN_EDITCHANGE(ID_TREEVIEWFILTER_COMBOBOX, Test)

But not hitting the function 'Test'. I have managed to catch other combo box messages eg. ON_CBN_DROPDOWN from in the toolbar class but not CBN_EDITCHANGE.

In my CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton derived class I override the CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton::CreateCombo function as shown:

```
CComboBox* FilterComboButton::CreateCombo(CWnd* pWndParent, const CRect& rect)
{
  CComboBox* pCombo = new CComboBox();
  if (!pCombo->Create(CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VSCROLL | WS_CHILD, CRect(25,0,175,FILTERTOOLBARHEIGHT), pWndParent, ID_TREEVIEWFILTER_COMBOBOX))
  {
    LOG("Failed to create FilterComboBox");
    delete pCombo;
    pCombo = NULL;
  }

  return pCombo;
}
```

Adding the code: `BOOL bSuccess = pCombo->ModifyStyle(CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, NULL);` after the call to CComboBox::Create causes me to receive the CBN_EDITCHANGE, but interferes with the function of the combobox.

I have managed to catch the edit controls message EN_UPDATE but not EN_CHANGE. This is so close but so far away...

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using Spy++ to: 1. verify that EN_CHANGE is being fired and 2. To determine who it is being sent to?

Comment: No I haven't - I will try that thanks!